# JavaScript Value Issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a very simple auto-price estimator for my team.

However I've wrote something out but I want the amount of pages to + 5 and add that to the price.

For example, if the wanted 1 page it would be +5 to the price or 3 pages it would be +15 to the price.

```js
$('#type, #pages').on('keyup change',function(){
    var page=$('#pages').val();   
    var type=$('#type').val();
    var price=  page + type ; 
    $('#price').val( price || 0 );
});
```

```html
How many pages does the client want: <input id="pages"/>

<br><br>

<div class="styled-select">    
    <select name="dropdown" id="type">
        <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="25">One Page Site</option>     
        <option value="15">Web Portal</option>      
        <option value="35">Multi-Site</option>      
        <option value="15">Other</option>    
    </select> 
</div> 
    <br> <br>
    Estimated Price of Project: <input id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that to achieve your desired output, you have to use `multiply` operation instead of `addition`.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var counter = +$('#pages').val();
    var type = +$('#type').val();
    $('#result').val(type + counter*5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
How many pages does the client want: <input id="pages"/>

<br><br>

<div class="styled-select">    
    <select name="dropdown" id="type">
        <option value="0">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="25">One Page Site</option>     
        <option value="15">Web Portal</option>      
        <option value="35">Multi-Site</option>      
        <option value="15">Other</option>    
    </select> 
</div> 
    <br> <br>
    Estimated Price of Project: <input id="result"/>
    
    <button type="button" id='btn'>Show the price</button>
```

Comment: How do I do this so I can get the total price once I press a submit button

Comment: @TrifleTower There were no any buttons in your question. But if you prefer this way, I've added it.

Comment: Problem with this. I want the type of project so a multi site would be 35 then I want plus 5 for each page. So 3 would be 15 and 5 would be 25.

EG: Multi-site = 35
3 pages = 15
35 + 15 = 50

But I got 105 as it timsed

Comment: @TrifleTower It's done. In this case, T.J. Crowder hints would be really helpful (:

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. The value of an input is always a string. In JavaScript, `+` with strings is concatenation ("1" + "2" = "12"). You need to convert your operands to numbers first, for instance (note the `+` signs):

   ```
   var page = +$('#pages').val();   
   var type = +$('#type').val();
   ```

   The unary `+` is just one way to convert those strings to numbers, see below for more.
2. If you want to add 5 for every page, you want `*`, not `+. As it happens,`*`converts its operands to numbers automatically (unlike`+`), so you could have got away without explicitly converting (though explicit conversion is best).

About converting to number: Your choices for doing so:

- The unary `+` operator:  `value = +value` will coerce the string to a number using the JavaScript engine's standard rules for that. Any non-digits in the string (other than the `e` for scientific notation) make the result `NaN`. Also, `+""` is `0`, which may not be intuitive.
- The `Number` function: `value = Number(value)`. Does the same thing as `+`.
- The `parseInt` function, usually with a radix (number base): `value = parseInt(value, 10)`. The downside here is that `parseInt` converts any number it finds at the beginning of the string but **ignores** non-digits later in the string, so `parseInt("100asdf", 10)` is `100`, not `NaN`. As the name implies, `parseInt` parses only a whole number.
- The `parseFloat` function: `value = parseFloat(value)`. Allows fractional values, and always works in decimal (never octal or hex). Does the same thing `parseInt` does with garbage at the end of the string, `parseFloat("123.34alksdjf")` is `123.34`.

So, pick your tool to suit your use case. :-)

Comment: I've checked it and it's not necessarily in this case.

Comment: @Kinduser: "It" what?

Comment: @Kinduser: With respect, you're mistaken: It is indeed true: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlinputelement See the definition of `value`: `[TreatNullAs=EmptyString] attribute DOMString value;`

Comment: Indeed, I see it now. They are strings but the multiplication operator `*` changes it into numbers immediately. But please tell me once again, is my way of thinking right? The desired result will be achieved only if using multiplication instead of addition?

Comment: @Kinduser: Yes, because `*` (unlike `+`) coerces its operands to number. It's not generally a good idea to rely on it, since minor edits to the equation can introduce a `+` and cause bugs due to concatenation. Better to explicitly convert first.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for a productive discussion (: